# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' when adding UINavigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to add a static UINavigation bar that will be present on a nearly all ViewControllers in my project.  The UINavigation bar will have the same 3 buttons throughout (one opens a side menu, one opens a search, one opens a ViewController to allow settings to be changed.

I have followed several tutorials (none are for Xcode5/iOS7) and these haven't worked for me.

Relevant code of "AppDelegate.m":

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
    UINavigationController *navVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    [navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mainVC]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:navVC];

    return YES;
}
```

Running this gives the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

MainViewController.m init

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

Thanks,

Edit:

To Clarify, I am using a storyboard called 'Main', many ViewControllers with the first one being loaded called 'MainVC' which has a custom class called 'MainViewController'.  Thanks to @LML the working code for this is now:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];
    MainViewController* mainVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    UINavigationController *navVC =[[UINavigationController alloc]       initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navVC];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What is your xib name? check whether `MainViewController.xib` or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this because you are using storyboard

-

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:...{   

// set to storyboard on launch
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhoneStoryboard"
                                                         bundle: nil];

MainViewController* mainVC = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
UINavigationController *navVC =[[UINavigationController alloc]    initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
[self.window setRootViewController:navVC];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible];
 return YES;
 }
```

Comment: This gives warning of 'undeclared identifier nibNameOrNil'

Comment: is your MainViewController class is a subclass or UIViewController and please replace nibName or nil with ur xib name  and nibBunble or nil with nil

Comment: It is just an obj-c class added to project that a ViewController has as it's class

Comment: That's it, you've fixed it!  Thanks a lot mate, and apologies for being unclear in my question, as you can tell, I'm an Obj-C n00b.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC]`.

Comment: Where should this be added?

Comment: Not added: it should replace your [[UINavigationController alloc] init].

Comment: This still gives error 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method-

```
MainViewController *mainVC = [MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navVC =[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC]; // Change here
[navVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mainVC]]; 
[self.window setRootViewController:navVC];

return YES;
```

Comment: This gives warning of 'undeclared identifier nibNameOrNil' and 'too many arguments for method call expects 1, have 2'

Comment: @Ryan - try updated ans. I am assuming you have nib file named "MainViewController" associated with "MainViewController" only. If you don't have this nib/xib then simply do [[MainViewController alloc] init];

Comment: Well is compiled this time but then gave error: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle .... (loaded)' with name 'MainViewController''

Comment: @Ryan - If you have nib/xib, then simply copy that name and put it there. And if not, then alloc simply as - [[MainViewController alloc] init];

Comment: @Ryan -make such things clear in question only! what u r using and what u did!! So that u can get perfect answer quickly!!

Comment: I have many UIViewControllers added to storyboard, the initial one is called MainVC and has a custom class called MainViewController.